# projet symfony dont display css and js and pictures

Tags: php, symfony

I created one project in symfony 2 I send it to my company but the project not working properly no fils css, no file js no pictures.
I'need my my laptop it works correctly.
So i connected remotly to my company
I excuted this command 
php app/console assetic:dump 
but I have this problem 
There are no commands defined in the "assetic" namespace.
    Did you mean this?
        assets

I don't know why I have this problem with this command. But 
php app/console assets:install it works correctly 
Thanks stack overflow
[image]

Comment: Starting from SF2.8, you should install the bundle manually, it's not included

Comment: Its the same project it's woks locally in my computer but not working in the computer of my company that mean that assetic is the integrated! !

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation is written that be used with:

`php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

maybe the directory seperator like \ and no /

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment

Answer (score 0):

this command belongs to this bundle
https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle
I think above bundle is not installed.

check your composer.json or vendor folder.